# How to fix watermark position php?

Tags: php, laravel

I want the watermark to be applied to a selected image, in 5 different positions, I have 3 function for these positions center, bottom_right, top_left which work with all images but i dont know how to do bottom_left, top_right. I tried but with different images the watermark disappears or appear somewhere wrong, here are the three functions that work. I need the watermark to be placed in every image the same position like responsive.

Center:

```
     $imgs = imagecreatefromjpeg("/var/www/$f$p/$n");

// Load the logo image
                    $logoImage = imagecreatefrompng("$waterpath/$watername");
                    imagealphablending($logoImage, true);

// Get dimensions
                    $imageWidth = imagesx($imgs);
                    $imageHeight = imagesy($imgs);

                    $logoWidth = imagesx($logoImage);
                    $logoHeight = imagesy($logoImage);

// Paste the logo
                    imagecopy(
                    // destination
                        $imgs,
                        // source
                        $logoImage,
                        // destination x and y
                        ($imageWidth - $logoWidth) / 2, ($imageHeight - $logoHeight) / 2,
                        // source x and y
                        0, 0,
                        // width and height of the area of the source to copy
                        $logoWidth, $logoHeight);
                    $watermark->update(array('status' => 'done'));

                    imagejpeg($imgs, "/var/www/$f$p/$n");
```

top_left:

```
     $imgs = imagecreatefromjpeg("/var/www/$f$p/$n");

// Load the logo image
                    $logoImage = imagecreatefrompng("$waterpath/$watername");
                    imagealphablending($logoImage, true);

                    // Get dimensions
                    $imageWidth = imagesx($imgs);
                    $imageHeight = imagesy($imgs);

                    $logoWidth = imagesx($logoImage);
                    $logoHeight = imagesy($logoImage);

                    // Paste the logo
                    imagecopy(
                    // destination
                        $imgs,
                        // source
                        $logoImage,
                        // destination x and y
                        ($imageWidth - $logoWidth) / 100, ($imageHeight - $logoHeight) / 100,
                        // source x and y
                        0, 0,
                        // width and height of the area of the source to copy
                        $logoWidth, $logoHeight);


                    imagejpeg($imgs, "/var/www/$f$p/$n");
```

bottom_right:

```
 $imgs = imagecreatefromjpeg("/var/www/$f$p/$n");

// Load the logo image
                    $stamps = imagecreatefrompng("$waterpath/$watername");

                    // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
                    $marge_right = 10;
                    $marge_bottom = 10;
                    $sx = imagesx($stamps);
                    $sy = imagesy($stamps);
                    $imageWidth = imagesx($imgs);
                    $imageHeight = imagesy($imgs);

                    // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo
                    // width to calculate positioning of the stamp.
                    imagecopy($imgs, $stamps, $imageWidth - $sx - $marge_right, $imageHeight - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamps), imagesy($stamps));

                    imagejpeg($imgs, "/var/www/$f$p/$n");
```

These functions i tried but they dont work with all images:

bottom_left:

```
 $imgs = imagecreatefromjpeg("/var/www/$f$p/$n");

// Load the logo image
                    $stamps = imagecreatefrompng("$waterpath/$watername");

                    // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
                    $marge_right = 670;
                    $marge_bottom = 10;
                    $sx = imagesx($stamps);
                    $sy = imagesy($stamps);
                    $imageWidth = imagesx($imgs);
                    $imageHeight = imagesy($imgs);


                    // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo
                    // width to calculate positioning of the stamp.
                    imagecopy($imgs, $stamps, $imageWidth - $sx - $marge_right, $imageHeight - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamps), imagesy($stamps));

                    imagejpeg($imgs, "/var/www/$f$p/$n");
```

top_right:

```
 $imgs = imagecreatefromjpeg("/var/www/$f$p/$n");

// Load the logo image
                    $stamps = imagecreatefrompng("$waterpath/$watername");

                    // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
                    $marge_right = 10;
                    $marge_bottom = 430;
                    $sx = imagesx($stamps);
                    $sy = imagesy($stamps);
                    $imageWidth = imagesx($imgs);
                    $imageHeight = imagesy($imgs);

                    // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo
                    // width to calculate positioning of the stamp.
                    imagecopy($imgs, $stamps, $imageWidth - $sx - $marge_right, $imageHeight - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamps), imagesy($stamps));

                    imagejpeg($imgs, "/var/www/$f$p/$n");
```

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, just an advice: PHP has a rich lib ecosystem, always check if there are alternatives to implementing more or less complicated things. Worst case scenario you can learn from the libs you find for the particular issue you're having. For example, a [lib like this one](https://github.com/Intervention/image) allows you to do things like this `$img->insert('public/watermark.png', 'bottom-right', 10, 10)` ([documentation](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert)).